# OSGI service component dependency couldn't resolved

Tags: java, osgi, command-line-arguments, osgi-bundle

I need to implement a calculator program in OSGI. For that I have created three bundles of jar called calculator api, calculator implementation and calculator bundle named as `cala-1.0.0.jar`, `cali-1.0.0.jar`, and `calb-1.0.0.jar`.

Within the calculator bundle class like this:

```
package org.cal.bun;

            import org.cal.api.calapi;

            //import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
            import org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandInterpreter;
            import org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider;

            /**
             * The Declarative Service Component for Hello Service
             *
             * @scr.component name="org.cal.bun.calculatorservice"
             * immediate="true"
             * @scr.reference name="org.wso2.cal"
             * interface="org.cal.api.calapi"
             * cardinality="1..1"
             * policy="static"
             * bind="bindcalapi"
             * unbind="unbindcalapi"
             */

            public class calculatorservice implements CommandProvider{

              private calapi s;


                public synchronized void bindcalapi(calapi s) {
                    this.s = s;
                }

                public synchronized void unbindcalapi(calapi s) {
                    this.s = null;
                }

                public synchronized void _run(CommandInterpreter ci) {
                    if (s != null) {
                        System.out.println("hi");
                    } else {
                        ci.println("Error, No Service of type Sayable available");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String getHelp() {
                    return null;
                }
```

and the `pom.xml` file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.0.0">
        <parent>
            <artifactId>cal</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.wso2.com</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </parent>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>calb</artifactId>
        <packaging>bundle</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.v20130814-1242</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.100.v20130513-1956</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wso2.com</groupId>
                <artifactId>cala</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>wso2-nexus</id>
                <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
                <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>


        <build>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>scr</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>

                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.5</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>

                    <configuration>

                        <instructions>

                            <Bundle-Vendor>Sample Inck</Bundle-Vendor>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>

                            <Import-Package>
                                org.cal.api.*;version=1.0.0,
                                org.osgi.*;,org.eclipse.osgi.framework.*;
                               org.osgi.service.component.*;

                            </Import-Package>




                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>




    </project>
```

When I run this program in OSGI console the following error appears on the console:

```
45  ACTIVE      cala_1.0.0
46  ACTIVE      cali_1.0.0
52  INSTALLED   calb_1.0.0
osgi> stop 45 46 52
osgi> start 45 46 52
gogo: BundleException: The bundle "calb_1.0.0 [52]" could not be resolved. Reason:     Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.component; version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"
```

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define an Import-Package for this package in your maven bundle plugin config. So you have to install a bundle that exports this package.

Try to install this bundle:
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html

Comment: Is the package really exported by the bundle you installed? If yes then the error can not happen. Perhaps the package version of the exported package does not match the import range you specified.